# generating function arguments in java

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to java and am working on my first Android app. I am using the webview demo as a template. I am trying to generate a random integer between 1 and 12 and then call a certain javascript function based on the result. Here's what I have:

```
int number = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((12 - 1) + 1));
number = (int) Math.floor(number);
String nextQuote = "javascript:wave" + number + "()";
mWebView.loadUrl(nextQuote);
```

So `mWebView.loadUrl(nextQuote)` will be the same as something like `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:wave1()")`

I just want to know if what I have here is correct and will work the way I think it will. The application isn't responding as expected and I suspect this bit of code is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key statement are as follows:

```
int number = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((12 - 1) + 1));
number = (int) Math.floor(number);
```

The first statement gives the answer you need, but in a rather cumbersome way.  Lets step through what happens:

1. `((12 - 1) + 1)` is `12`.  (This is evaluated at compile time ... )
2. `Math.random()` gives a `double` in the range `0.0D <= rd < 1.0D`.
3. `Math.random() * 12` gives a `double` in the range `0.0D <= rd < 12.0D`.
4. The `(int)` cast converts the `double` to an `int` by rounding towards zero.  In other words `(int)(Math.random() * 12)` will be a integer in the range `0 <= ri <= 11`.
5. Finally you add `1` giving an integer in the range `1 <= ri <= 12`.

`W**5` :-)

A simpler and clearer version would be:

```
private static Random rand = new Random();
...
int number = 1 + rand.nextInt(12);
```

The second statement is (as far as I can tell) a noop.  It implicitly converts an `int` to a `double`, gets the `double` form of largest integer that is less or equal to that `double`, and converts that back to an `int`.  The result will always be identical to the original `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Documention of Java Random Class
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

A good way to do this.

```
Random rand = new Random();               // does not have to be static but can be.
int number = rand.nextInt(12) + 1;        // 1 to 12 Must use 12 
                                          // Range is 0-11 add 1: 1-12
String nextQuote = "javascript:wave" + number + "()";
mWebView.loadUrl(nextQuote);
```

** from Java doc ** Method: public int nextInt(int n)

"Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)"